# Concurrent Queue using Ada SPARK with the Ravenscar profile

Tags: concurrency, queue, ada

See here: https://gitlab.com/linted/linted/blob/162b5e9fba53a90b3c6d78e214776e069c3c722b/src/ada-core/src/linted-queues.adb

The code implements a concurrent queue.

It can't allocate memory or use many other niceties because memory allocations are difficult to reason about with formal methods. So the package has to use its own storage pool.

The code has to use a Wait_List and basically reimplement Suspension_Object because I've got restrictions on that prevent multiple tasks blocking on one thing at once.

I'm unsure about some of the volatility and atomics stuff. I'm pretty sure I safely hand out `Node_Not_Null_Access` values so that no two tasks use the same `Node_Not_Null_Access` value at once. However, I may be missing an Atomic or Volatile pragma that will let two tasks safely use two array elements that are right next to each other.

linted-queues.ads

```
 -- Copyright 2016 Steven Stewart-Gallus
 --
 -- Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 -- you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 -- You may obtain a copy of the License at
 --
 --     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 --
 -- Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 -- distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 -- WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
 -- implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
 -- permissions and limitations under the License.
 generic
    type Element_T is private;
    Max_Nodes_In_Flight : Positive;
 package Linted.Queues with
    Spark_Mode,
    Abstract_State => (State with External) is
    pragma Elaborate_Body;

    type Queue is limited private;

    procedure Insert (Q : in out Queue; C : Element_T) with
       Global => (In_Out => State),
       Depends => (State => (State, Q, C), Q => (State, Q, C));
    procedure Remove
      (Q : in out Queue;
       C : out Element_T;
       Init : out Boolean) with
       Global => (In_Out => State),
       Depends =>
       (State => (State, Q),
        Q => (State, Q),
        C => (State, Q),
        Init => (State, Q));

 private
    type Node_Access is new Natural;
    subtype Node_Not_Null_Access is Node_Access range 1 .. Node_Access'Last;

    protected type Queue is
       procedure Insert (N : Node_Not_Null_Access);
       procedure Remove (N : out Node_Access);
    private
       First : Node_Access := 0;
       Last : Node_Access := 0;
    end Queue;

 end Linted.Queues;
```

linted-queues.adb

```
 -- Copyright 2016 Steven Stewart-Gallus
 --
 -- Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 -- you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 -- You may obtain a copy of the License at
 --
 --     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 --
 -- Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 -- distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 -- WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
 -- implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
 -- permissions and limitations under the License.
 with Linted.Wait_Lists;

 package body Linted.Queues with
      Refined_State =>
      (State => (Elements, Tails, In_Queues, Spare_Nodes, Triggers))
 is

    Elements : array
    (1 .. Node_Not_Null_Access (Max_Nodes_In_Flight)) of Element_T;
    Tails : array
    (1 .. Node_Not_Null_Access (Max_Nodes_In_Flight)) of Node_Access :=
      (others => 0);
    In_Queues : array
    (1 .. Node_Not_Null_Access (Max_Nodes_In_Flight)) of Boolean :=
      (others => False) with
       Ghost;

    Spare_Nodes : Queue;
    Triggers : Wait_Lists.Wait_List;

    procedure Allocate (N : out Node_Not_Null_Access) with
       Post => Is_Free (N);
    procedure Free (N : Node_Not_Null_Access) with
       Pre => Is_Free (N);

    function Is_Free (N : Node_Not_Null_Access) return Boolean is
    begin
       return not In_Queues (N);
    end Is_Free;

    protected body Queue is
       procedure Insert (N : Node_Not_Null_Access) is
       begin
          pragma Assert (not In_Queues (N));
          pragma Assert (Tails (N) = 0);

          In_Queues (N) := True;

          if First = 0 or Last = 0 then
             First := Node_Access (N);
          else
             Tails (Last) := Node_Access (N);
          end if;
          Last := Node_Access (N);
       end Insert;

       procedure Remove (N : out Node_Access) is
       begin
          if First = 0 or Last = 0 then
             N := 0;
          else
             declare
                Removed : Node_Access;
             begin
                Removed := First;
                pragma Assert (In_Queues (Removed));
                First := Tails (Removed);
                In_Queues (Removed) := False;
                Tails (Removed) := 0;

                N := Removed;
             end;
          end if;
       end Remove;
    end Queue;

    procedure Free (N : Node_Not_Null_Access) is
       Dummy : Element_T;
    begin
       Elements (N) := Dummy;
       Spare_Nodes.Insert (N);
       Wait_Lists.Signal (Triggers);
    end Free;

    procedure Allocate (N : out Node_Not_Null_Access) is
       Dummy : Element_T;
       Removed : Node_Access;
    begin
       loop
          Spare_Nodes.Remove (Removed);
          if Removed /= 0 then
             exit;
          end if;
          Wait_Lists.Wait (Triggers);
       end loop;
       N := Node_Not_Null_Access (Removed);
       Elements (N) := Dummy;
    end Allocate;

    procedure Insert (Q : in out Queue; C : Element_T) is
       --  FAKE!
       N : Node_Not_Null_Access := 1;
    begin
       Allocate (N);
       Elements (N) := C;
       Q.Insert (N);
    end Insert;

    procedure Remove
      (Q : in out Queue;
       C : out Element_T;
       Init : out Boolean)
    is
       Removed : Node_Access;
    begin
       Q.Remove (Removed);
       if Removed = 0 then
          Init := False;
       else
          declare
             N : Node_Not_Null_Access := Node_Not_Null_Access (Removed);
          begin
             C := Elements (N);
             Free (N);
             Init := True;
          end;
       end if;
    end Remove;

 begin
    for II in 1 .. Node_Not_Null_Access (Max_Nodes_In_Flight) loop
       declare
          N : Node_Not_Null_Access := II;
       begin
          Spare_Nodes.Insert (N);
       end;
    end loop;
 end Linted.Queues;
```

And the supporting wait list code which I'm not as concerned about. I think I might need to make the suspension objects be passed in manually instead of allocated on the stack for it to be possible for certain formal analyses such as WCET to work properly.

linted-wait_lists.ads

```
 -- Copyright 2016 Steven Stewart-Gallus
 --
 -- Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 -- you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 -- You may obtain a copy of the License at
 --
 --     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 --
 -- Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 -- distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 -- WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
 -- implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
 -- permissions and limitations under the License.
 package Linted.Wait_Lists with
      Spark_Mode is
    pragma Preelaborate;

    type Wait_List is limited private;

    procedure Wait (W : in out Wait_List) with
       Global => null,
       Depends => (W => W);
    procedure Broadcast (W : in out Wait_List) with
       Global => null,
       Depends => (W => W);
    procedure Signal (W : in out Wait_List) with
       Global => null,
       Depends => (W => W);

 private
    pragma SPARK_Mode (Off);

    type Node;
    type Node_Nonnull_Access is not null access all Node;
    type Node_Access is access all Node;

    protected type Wait_List is
       procedure Insert (N : Node_Nonnull_Access);
       procedure Remove (N : Node_Nonnull_Access);
       procedure Broadcast;
       procedure Signal;
    private
       First : Node_Access;
       Last : Node_Access;
    end Wait_List;
 end Linted.Wait_Lists;
```

linted-wait_lists.adb

```
 -- Copyright 2016 Steven Stewart-Gallus
 --
 -- Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 -- you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 -- You may obtain a copy of the License at
 --
 --     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 --
 -- Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 -- distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 -- WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
 -- implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
 -- permissions and limitations under the License.
 with Ada.Synchronous_Task_Control;

 package body Linted.Wait_Lists with
      Spark_Mode => Off is
    package STC renames Ada.Synchronous_Task_Control;

    type Node is record
       Trigger : STC.Suspension_Object;
       Prev_Trigger : Node_Access;
       Next_Trigger : Node_Access;
    end record;

    protected body Wait_List is
       procedure Insert (N : Node_Nonnull_Access) is
       begin
     pragma Assert (N.Next_Trigger = null);
     pragma Assert (N.Prev_Trigger = null);

          if First = null or Last = null then
             First := Node_Access (N);
          else
        N.Prev_Trigger := Last;
             Last.Next_Trigger := Node_Access (N);
          end if;
          Last := Node_Access (N);
       end Insert;

       procedure Remove (N : Node_Nonnull_Access) is
     Prev : Node_Access;
     Next : Node_Access;
       begin
     Prev := N.Prev_Trigger;
     Next := N.Next_Trigger;

     if null = Prev then
        First := Next;
     else
        Prev.Next_Trigger := Next;
     end if;

     if null = Next then
        Last := Prev;
     else
        Next.Prev_Trigger := Prev;
     end if;
       end Remove;

       procedure Broadcast is
          Current_Trigger : Node_Access;
       begin
          Current_Trigger := First;
          loop
             if null = Current_Trigger then
                exit;
             end if;
             STC.Set_True (Current_Trigger.Trigger);
             Current_Trigger := Current_Trigger.Next_Trigger;
          end loop;
       end Broadcast;

       procedure Signal is
          Current_Trigger : Node_Access;
       begin
          Current_Trigger := First;

          if Current_Trigger /= null then
             STC.Set_True (Current_Trigger.Trigger);
          end if;
       end Signal;
    end Wait_List;

    procedure Wait (W : in out Wait_List) is
       N : aliased Node;
    begin
       W.Insert (N'Unchecked_Access);
       STC.Suspend_Until_True (N.Trigger);
       W.Remove (N'Unchecked_Access);
    end Wait;

    procedure Broadcast (W : in out Wait_List) is
    begin
       W.Broadcast;
    end Broadcast;

    procedure Signal (W : in out Wait_List) is
    begin
       W.Signal;
    end Signal;
 end Linted.Wait_Lists;
```